# Python logging a consola y fichero a la vez no funciona

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, consola, log

Estoy tratando (por primera vez) de sacar un log por consola y a un fichero a la vez, pero no logro que funcione como debería.
He reducido el código al script de ejemplo que adjunto, y que no funciona.

```
import logging

log_format = '[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)-8s [%(name)s.%(funcName)-10s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s'
log_date = '%Y-%m-%d T%H:%M:%S'
logging.basicConfig(format=log_format,
                    datefmt=log_date
                    )

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# controlador para consola
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
console_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)

# controlador para fichero
log_file = 'c:/testpython/debug/registro_handler_individual.log'
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='w')
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#añadir los distintos controladores al registro
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)


def factorial(n):
    f = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        f *= i
        logger.debug(f'Bucle:{i} Valor:{f}')
    return f

logger.info('factorial(4)')
print(factorial(4))
logger.warning('finalización factorial')
```

Debería sacar a la consola las entrada de INFO y superiores y a fichero las de DEBUG y superiores, pero en la consola obtengo:

```
24
finalización factorial
[2022-01-14 T14:52:06] WARNING  [__main__.<module>  :34] finalización factorial
```

Y en el fichero solo aparece:

```
finalización factorial
```

Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo rematadamente mal?

Answer (score 1):

Para quién pueda interesar, aquí va una solución.

Después de muchos intentos y de rebuscar (que no encontrar) información, he llegado a la conclusión que si creo una configuración básica con logging.basicConfig(), es el nivel de configuración que se defina en esa función la que marca el nivel para todos los manejadores.
Conclusión: No hay que establecer una configuración básica y hacerlo manejador a manejador. Así, el código siguiente si saca por consola los mensajes de su nivel y a fichero los del suyo.

```
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# controlador para consola
console_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
streamformat = logging.Formatter("%(levelname)s:%(module)s:%(message)s")
console_handler.setFormatter(streamformat)
console_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)

# controlador para fichero
log_file = 'c:/testpython/debug/registro_handler_individual-TEST.log'
log_format = logging.Formatter('[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)-8s [%(name)s.%(funcName)-10s:%(lineno)d] %(message)s')
file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file, mode='w')
file_handler.setFormatter(log_format)
file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

#añadir los distintos controladores al registro
logger.addHandler(console_handler)
logger.addHandler(file_handler)


logger.debug('debug')
logger.info('info')
logger.warning('warning')
logger.error('error')
logger.critical('critical')
```

En consola aparecen:

```
WARNING:log_handler_individual-TEST:warning
ERROR:log_handler_individual-TEST:error
CRITICAL:log_handler_individual-TEST:critical
```

Y en el fichero tenemos:

```
[2022-01-15 10:39:28,417] DEBUG    [__main__.<module>  :31] debug
[2022-01-15 10:39:28,417] INFO     [__main__.<module>  :32] info
[2022-01-15 10:39:28,417] WARNING  [__main__.<module>  :33] warning
[2022-01-15 10:39:28,424] ERROR    [__main__.<module>  :34] error
[2022-01-15 10:39:28,427] CRITICAL [__main__.<module>  :35] critical
```